# Referencing current row while extended a matrix

Tags: matlab, octave

How to refer to current row in element-wise operation involving a matrix. This would be analogous to *this* pointer in C++.

Specifically, I am trying to add another column to a matrix 'A' where each new cell value is calculated using scaler-vector comparison between an existing element in current row.

For example:

```
A = [1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10];
B = [2;4;6;5;3];
```

I want 'C' to contain a second column that contains the count of all elements less than the corresponding row element in A. Like so:

```
C = 
 1  0
 2  0
 3  1
 4  2
 5  3
 6  4
 7  5
 8  5
 9  5
 10  5
```

I figured it should be possible to do this using scaler-vector comparison & summing over the results (i.e. `sum(B<A)`). This does not work:

```
>> C = [A, sum(B<A)]
error: mx_el_lt: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 5x1, op2 is 10x1)
```

Here the octave interpreter treats A (inside `A<B` statement) as a vector. I am unclear why is that the case, as something like following lines of code works as expected (i.e. octave treats A as scaler element in current row):

```
>> D = [A, A + 5];
D =
    1    6
    2    7
    3    8
    4    9
    5   10
    6   11
    7   12
    8   13
    9   14
   10   15
```

Question: What is the correct way to accomplish what I am doing? Is there a way to refer to "current row variable" in element wise statements (i.e. something like C = [A, sum(B

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to do.

When you say "I want 'C' to contain a second column that contains the sum of all elements less than the corresponding row element in A", what exactly do you mean?

Also, in `sum(A<B)` A and B have different dimensions, you can't really compare them in that way.

Comment: So for example. The fifth row in 'A' is 5. The count of elements in 'B' less than 5 is 3 and can be obtained by doing `sum(B<5)`. Now 'A' is `10x1` vector but in the context of `[]` operator A should be treated as a scaler with a value of 'current row' like it is done in last example I demonstrated (i.e. calculate D).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there, but as @Guille mentioned it won't work because you have two vectors of different dimensions. However you could create a Matrix from those values, which is the comparison of each value of A ('current row') with B:

```
A = [1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10];
B = [2;4;6;5;3];

C=[A sum(B'<A,2)];  %B'<A creates a 5x10 matrix and ',2' in sum adds up rowwise
```

Comment: Great! I think the question came from my mistaken understanding of `[ ]` operation as a row by row sequential operation (due to my background in imperative programming languages like C++). `[ ]` is just a merge between multiple matrices where different variables don't have any special meaning in context of `[ ]`. Thanks!